# Where are the turret terminals in the map Fracture?

Tags: titanfall

turrets have terminals nearby them that you can hack to get them to fight for you. On most maps that have turrets the terminal is right next to the turret. On the map Fracture, however, the turrets are a bit more elevated and harder to reach. The terminals also seem to be not directly next to them like in other maps. Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The turrets on Fracture are cosmetic, and are not hack-able.** They are meant to be the reason the IMC wants to control the hardpoints in the first campaign mission "The Refuling Raid".